# Problem with Django syncdb on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-ec2, mysql-python

I'm trying to deploy my project on my EC2 instance.
When I run `python manage.py validate` I get this error `Error: No module named mysql.base`
.

I have already installed MySQL-python using `yum install MySQL-python`. I can import MySQLdb successfully from the Python interpreter.

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong?

I am using Django 1.3 and Python 2.6 and MySQLdb 1.2.3c1

**UPDATE**
Ok, I found the MySQL-python file in the following directory `/usr/lib**64**/python2.6/site-packages/` and not in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`. So now I am trying to download the MySQL-python file manually via `wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/1.2.3/MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz/download` whilst in my `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/` directory and now I am getting this error when I run `python setup.py build`

```
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -DUNIV_LINUX
unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

OS Details

```
Amazon Linux AMI Base 2011.02.1, EBS boot, 64-bit architecture with Amazon EC2 AMI Tools
The Amazon Linux AMI is based on RHEL 5.x and parts of RHEL6
```

**UPDATE**
I re-did the project on a 32 bit instance and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
pip install mysql-python
```

or

```
easy_install mysql-python
```

or download the package and then install using python script setup.py

EDIT:

Try to do the import on a python shell

```
from mysql.base import *
```

or just launch

```
python manage.py shell
```

If you are able to do so it is possible that there's something wrong in /home/djangotest/sgelections/apache/django.wsgi

an extreme example (lol):

```
import sys
sys.path = []
```

Comment: I tried easy_install and downloading the package manually and it still doesnt work.

Comment: I tried `from mysql.base import *` and `python manage.py shell`. They both resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? 
Was python 2.6 installed by default of did you install that yourself?

The reason why I'm asking is because when you use yum install it is going to install the mysql-python client for the version of python installed on your OS, for CentOS 5.5 it was python2.4.x.

If you installed python2.6 manually using the alt-install option of python, then mysql-python is most likley installed for the default version of python on your machine but not you python2.6.

If you go into /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages do you see a MySQL_python there? If not then you will need to either install it again using easy_install or pip, or download the mysql-python package yourself and then manually install it. Or you can add where ever it is installed now to your python path.

If you search for MySQL_python on your machine, you can see where it is installed now and that should give you a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Python2.6 came with my ec2 instance. I tried easy_install but it still didn't work.

Comment: What Linux distro and version are you using? Did you look in site packages to see if mysql-python was there?

Comment: I've updated question to reflect progress in solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

Open your `settings.py` file. If you make the `ENGINE` into `mySQL`, you should change it like this:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 
      'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
  ...
     }
```